# Adding onClick event dynamic DOM Object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm coding basic balloon game. Balloons are created dynamically into the canvas. Everything is ok but I could not add `onclick` event to hide the balloon. First function to start game is `Baslat()`. Here is my code:

```
var canvas; 
var sev = 1;
var zorluk = 3;
var ctx;

function Baslat() {
    var x;
    for (x = 1; x <= sev*zorluk; x++) {
        BalonYap(x);
    }
}

function seviye(a) {
    sev = a.value;
}

function BalonYap(id) {

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "balon.png";
    img.id = "balon_"+id;
    img.onload = BalonLoad(img); // works
    img.onclick = Patlat(id); // doesn't work
    
}

function BalonLoad(img) {
    var rnd1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750)+10;
    var rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() *350)+10;
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(img, rnd1, rnd2);
}

function Patlat(img) {
    alert();
}
```

Comment: `img.onclick = function(){Patlat(id);}`

Comment: I've also used "img.onclick = function(){Patlat(id);}" but it did not work. I'm not expert on Javascript, I'm PHP Developer. I just improve myself on javascript. Should I use onclick event in Canvas for all balloons' coordinates ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign function to event handlers. If you give arguments to a function it's called. You can try this factory method (you can give arbitrary parameters to the wrapping function and use them inside the returned function's closure):

```
function BalonLoad(img) {
    return function() {
        var rnd1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750)+10;
        var rnd2 = Math.floor(Math.random() *350)+10;
        canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(img, rnd1, rnd2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the `onload` first and then the `src`, maybe it loads before you attach the listener. Also you may want to add the image to the DOM to fire events on it. (Disclaimer: these are just helpful guesses, based on past experiences)

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue here is that you are attempting to assign an event callback on an element that does not exist in the DOM. You are only drawing to the canvas. A click event will need to be applied to the canvas element. You will need to save the coordinates of each balloon, and use that to find the appropriate balloon when the canvas is clicked.

Comment: So, I guess I can't do what I want, like this way. Should I get all the image coordinates and add onclick event to the canvas ?

Comment: That would be my first thought. When drawing the Balloons to the canvas, save their starting coordinates in an object and maybe their size if that varies as well. Hiding a balloon in the canvas would mean redrawing without a balloon image at the coordinates of the clicked balloon and removing it from the coordinates object. I hope this helps!